# Unity Save load Int securely

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, save, load

I need C# code for Unity that saves and loads an int in some secure manner compatible with: iOS, Android, Windows, Mac, Linux. It doesn't have to be super secure, but at least the player can't just change it by opening it with notepad or something like that.

I don't care how anymore, or whether it is super encrypted secure, or just a case of simply converting the data, whether it uses player prefs converting to bytes (been trying to no avail) or whether to create a new file where the game is installed that is encrypted in some manner. Just something that works!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should check out this plugin:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32357

Free and easy to use. You initialize it first with

```
ZPlayerPrefs.Initialize("somePasswordString", "someSaltString");
```

The to useit:

```
// Write
ZPlayerPrefs.SetInt("foo", 10);
// Read
int i = ZPlayerPrefs.GetInt("foo", -1 /*default value*/ );
```

The encryption used there is quite weak (DES), but if you say you don't need it super secure that will do. And it will work on all platforms, as it uses `PlayerPrefs` as backend, which is cross platform.

There is also something similar here http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/playerprefs-encryption.26437/
but it is very weak, just MD5 checksum with some salt to check nobody messed with your data.

If you need strong encryption, I suggest you check out SOOMLA framework, which implements AES encrypted `KeyValueStorage` natively using a database.
Adding a stronger encryption in C# without native code may be a challenge, since Mono does not implement many System.Security.Cryptography classes, so you will have to do most of the job manually.